# `integer expression expected`

Tags: shell

I encountered `integer expression expected` error in the following code:

```
    #! /bin/bash
    # test integer: evaluate the value of integer
    int=-5
    if [ -z "$int" ]; then
        echo 'int is empty.' >&2
    fi

    if [ "$int" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "int is zero"
    else
        if [ '$int' -lt 0 ]; then
            echo "int is negative."
        else
            echo 'int is positive.'
        fi
        if [ $((int % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
            echo 'int is even.'
        else
            echo 'int is odd.'
        fi
    fi
```

Run it and get error report

```
    $ bash test_integer.sh
    test_integer.sh: line 14: [: $int: integer expression expected
    int is positive.
    int is odd.
```

I checked multiple times but fail to locate the bug,
which seem to line-to-line comform to the book

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ | Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide | Ref: http://gnu.org/s/bash/manual | http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/ | http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes | **Check your script: http://www.shellcheck.net/** And avoid people recommendations saying to learn with tldp.org web site, the tldp bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'$int'` is a quoting error which you would have easily seen if you had run the script through

```
bash -vx schript.sh
```

There is no expansion within single quotes. You need:

```
if [ "$int" -lt 0 ]
```